# add and remove wrapInner depending on screen size

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I'm trying to add and remove wrapInner depending on screen size. Is this possible?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {

        $('.homeNewsHeading > h3').wrapInner('<a href="#text" class="newcss" />');

    } else if (window.innerWidth > 768) {

    // How do I Remove the above wrapInner a-tag from the h3-tag?

    }
}).resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {

        $('.homeNewsHeading > h3').wrapInner('<a id="your-tag" href="#text" class="newcss" />');

    } else if (window.innerWidth > 768) {

        $('.homeNewsHeading > h3').text($('.homeNewsHeading > h3').text());

        $('#your-tag').remove();

    }
}).resize();
```

Comment: how it will delete children, it will remove just newly added tag

Comment: Hi, it did remove the children text too.

Answer (score 0):

.innerWrap was working when I made the screen smaller, .unwrap was when I made it bigger, but only on refresh, not dynamically. I don't know why but only this worked for me:

**HTML**

```
<div class="homeNewsHeading">
    <h3>Latest News</h3>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {

        $('.homeNewsHeading > h3').wrapInner('<a href="#text" class="newcss" />');

    } else if (window.innerWidth > 768) {

        $('.homeNewsHeading > h3').replaceWith('<h3>Latest News</h3>');

    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
        $('.homeNewsHeading > h3').wrapInner('<a href="#text" class="newcss" />');
    } else if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
        $('.homeNewsHeading > h3').find('.newcss').children().unwrap();
    }
}).resize();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kp7QU/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var appendsToggle = function(){

    var title = $('h2');

    if($(window).width() < 768){

        $(title).each(function(){
            if(!$(this).find('a').length)
                $(this).wrapInner('<a href="#"></a>');
        });

    }else{
        $(title).each(function(){
            if($(this).find('a').length)
                $(this).html($(this).find('a').html());
        });
    }
}
appendsToggle();
$(window).resize(appendsToggle);
```